# Nuget Error: Unable to read beyond the end of the stream

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, nuget

I'm facing this issue from time to time where I can't install new packages to my project, Nuget keeps showing this error, from the command shell and GUI.

I installed/reinstalled NuGet to no avail.

Can anyone point out possible reasons/solutions for this?

[image]

Comment: File permission denied for reading config files ? Try with VS as administrator ?

Comment: I'm running VS as administrator.
I tried removing certain entries from packages.config and it seems to work, need to know now why are these entries crashing nuget

Comment: What entries did you remove? Would you provide their XML?

Comment: They were entries specific to my project, nothing general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok Fixed.

It seems the issue was with packages installed on my machine.

I started commenting the packages.config entries one by one and see if the issue was resolved, once I identified few packages as problematic, I removed their entries from the packages.config file and removed the directories associated with them from the "packages" folder (some of the folders had missing .nuspec files, I assume that caused issues).

after that I reinstalled the packages that I removed and everything works perfectly now.